# SSL Handshake Error on Mobile app recording using Jmeter

Tags: iphone, mobile, jmeter, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to record an native app in iOS.

- The windows machine and iOS device are on same wifi network.
- Firewall is turned off on windows machine.
- Have genrated the ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt and installed on the iOS device.
- Enabled the full trust for root certificate.
- Changed the proxy to manual and provided the IP of my local windows machine and port.

I have done all necessary steps for recording, still I get the response as; Remote host terminated the handshake **ensure browser is set to accept the Jmeter proxy certificate**

What else am I missing, can anyone help here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your steps seem to be valid, however given the error it doesn't seem that you installed the JMeter's certificate and/or enabled full trust, we need to know exact full steps preferably with screenshots and see the [full JMeter log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) preferably with [debug logging enabled for the proxy components](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/), add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
```

Alternatively you can use [Charles Proxy](https://apps.apple.com/app/charles-proxy/id1134218562) to capture your mobile traffic, you can either build [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers manually or transfer the captured requests from iOS to desktop applications, [export them to HAR](https://doc.octoperf.com/design/create-virtual-user/record-charles-har/) and convert them into a JMeter Test using i.e. [BlazeMeter Converter](https://converter.blazemeter.com/)